# using multiple header, footer when using thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

when using thymeleaf, i created a seperate header and footer. but when i'm using it in another page it will generate error in IDE since `xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org` is not there. but the code is working in chrome. how can i eliminate error in IDE?

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head th:fragment="head">

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title> Data Tables</title>
<!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css}">
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/font-awesome.min.css}">
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css}">
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/fonts.css}">
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/AdminLTE.min.css}">
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/_all-skins.min.css}">
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/style.css}">
</head>
```

header.html

```
    <div th:replace="fragments/head.html :: head "></div>
    <div th:replace="fragments/header.html :: header"></div>
    <div th:replace="fragments/sidenav.html :: sidenav"></div>
    <div th:replace="fragments/footer.html  :: footer"></div>
```

index.html

in index.html there is an error

Comment: Could you give more info : wich IDE are you using and a simple example too. Thanks

Comment: i used inteliJ IDEA as IDE